# Normal behaviour of resolvedUrl in getServerSideProps in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using Next.js. When I go directly to `localhost:3000/about` page the `console.log(resolvedUrl)` in my `getServerSideProps` shows "`/`"

If I go to `localhost:3000/about?page=1` through `<Link href="/about?page=1">` the console log shows me `/about?page=1`.

Is this normal behavior of next to show "`/`" on any GET request which was performed not throught `<Link>`?

My code:

```
const AboutPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Link href="/about?page=1">Next page</Link>
        </div>
    );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res, resolvedUrl }) => {
    console.log(resolvedUrl)

    return {
        props: {
            data: null
        }
    }
}

export default AboutPage
```